# Get items with 0 Counts after GroupBy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the total count of records for past 5 days, based on a boolean `IsInsert`. The below query **neglects all the days with zero Total**.

```
SELECT CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE) AS ChangeDate
    ,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM CarrierRate.VendorBillUVBLog V WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE V.IsInsert = 1
    AND v.ChangeDate >= DATEADD(d, - 4, GETDATE())
    AND v.ChangeDate <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE) DESC
```

I have checked some other questions but they all address when a join is involved. Thank you.

Comment: Does that statement return rows with 0 total??

Comment: It returns days with non zero count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the second half of Gordon's answer, you also need to add the condition of your `WHERE` clause to the join between `Days` and `VendorBillUVBLog`.

```
with days as 
    (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 1 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 2 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 3 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 4 as date) as dd 
     )

select d.dd, count(v.ChangeDate)
from 
    days d 
     left join
    CarrierRate.VendorBillUVBLog V WITH(NOLOCK) on 
        cast(v.ChangeDate as date) = days.d AND
        V.IsInsert = 1  -- this line here needs to be part of the JOIN condition, not part of the WHERE
group by d.dd
order by d.dd;
```

The reason you need to put this in the JOIN, rather than the WHERE, is because you want all the days returned from the first table whether or not there are any valid rows in the other table.

If you add a filter using the where clause, you are effectively saying "retrieve all rows from the first table (Days), and any rows from the second table (VendorBill).  Only return rows from either table that meet condition *x*."

Since you want to see rows from the first table even when there aren't any rows that meet condition *x*, you need a query that says "retrieve all rows from the first table (days).  Also return any rows from the second table that meet *x* criteria". This is best accomplished with the `JOIN` condition, as above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the easiest way to solve this problem is using conditional aggregation.  If you have data for all days, but some of the data fails to meet the `v.IsInsert = 1` condition, then this is sufficient:

```
 SELECT CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE) AS ChangeDate, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN V.IsInsert = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total 
 FROM CarrierRate.VendorBillUVBLog V WITH(NOLOCK)    
 WHERE v.ChangeDate >= DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE()) AND
       v.ChangeDate <= GETDATE()    
 GROUP BY CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE) 
 ORDER BY CAST(V.ChangeDate AS DATE) DESC ;
```

Otherwise, you need to set up a list of days and use that:

```
with days as (
      select cast(getdate() as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 1 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 2 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 3 as date) as dd union all
      select cast(getdate() - 4 as date) as dd 
     )
select d.dd, count(v.ChangeDate)
from days d left join
     CarrierRate.VendorBillUVBLog V WITH(NOLOCK)  
     on cast(v.ChangeDate as date) = d.dd
group by d.dd
order by d.dd;
```

Comment: I had tried your first solution earlier, but there are some days without any records.

Didn't understand the second solution. I plainly copy pasted it and it says `'date' is not a recognized built-in function name`. the line with 'on' clause

Comment: @adiga . . . `date()` was a typo or withful thinking.

Comment: now showing this error `"The multi-part identifier "days.d" could not be bound"`

Comment: @adiga . . .  I have an impressive ability to confuse even myself, sometimes.  I try to suppress it ;)